# Is there a standard-library "print_to_string" function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if there is a function in the standard library that takes whatever the print function would print and returns it as a string. It seems like there ought to be but if it's there I'm not looking in the right spot.

My situation is I've done a programming exercise that creates (after some calculation) a string of digits stored in a list, e,g,

```
digits=[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

and the position of a decimal point `dp=4`

and I want to roll this into something that looks like a decimal. The print function works nicely to display what I want:

```
print(*(digits[:dp + 1] + ['.'] + digits[dp + 1:]), sep='')
```

produces `10010.10001`

but if I want to return this result as a string is seems I have to write additional code. Not that it would be difficult but it's unnecessary if there's something already built-in. None of print, format or the % operator seem to do the trick. The closest thing I could find was the StringIO class but I was hoping for something a bit simpler and less arcane.

Comment: @BartoszKP: Nah, this is the right question for the wrong answers to that question.

Comment: but printing to a StringIO buffer is simple and non-arcane.

Comment: Just an aside, it would be neater to use [(x) for x in digits].insert(dp+1, '.') to add the decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own function which behaves pretty similar to `print` like this (untested, have no python on tablet):

```
def print_to_string(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n'):
     return sep.join(str(obj) for obj in objects) + end
```

The `file` argument in [print](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print) does not make a lot of sense for strings.

Comment: So I take it that the answer is there is nothing built it, but I could put this in MyLib.py and get essentially the same effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can give an alternate buffer to the print statement:

```
>>> import io
>>> buf=io.StringIO()
>>> print('hello',file=buf)
>>> buf.getvalue()
'hello\n'
>>>
```

Comment: or print >>buf, "hello"

Comment: also, cStringIO is supposedly faster ?

Comment: @ychaouche - This is a python3 example where cStringIO and the '>>' print thing have gone away. Judging from the way the poster wrote his print statement, I think he's using python3.

Answer (score 1):

Python3's print function [will call write method of the file argument](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print)

If you don't like using StringIO, you can write your own:

```
class StringWrapper:
  def __init__(self): 
    self.string = "";
  def write(self, string):
    self.string += string
```

This is used with the file argument:

```
s = StringWrapper()
print("foo", "bar", file=s)
# s.string will be "foo bar\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the join command on strings - first you must convert your digits to strings:

```
sdigits = [str(i) for i in digits]
''.join(sdigits[:dp+1] + ['.'] + sdigits[dp+1:])
>>> '10010.10001
```